# Python 3D interpolation speedup

Tags: python, performance, numpy, interpolation, cython

I have following code used to interpolate 3D volume data.

```
Y, X, Z = np.shape(volume)
xs = np.arange(0, X)
ys = np.arange(0, Y)
zs = np.arange(0, Z)

points = list(zip(np.ravel(result[:, :, :, 1]), np.ravel(result[:, :, :, 0]), np.ravel(result[:, :, :, 2])))
interp = interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator((ys, xs, zs), volume,
                                             bounds_error=False, fill_value=0, method='linear')
new_volume = interp(points)
new_volume = np.reshape(new_volume, (Y, X, Z))
```

This code takes about 37 seconds to execute on 512x512x110 volume (about 29 millions of points), which results in more than one microsecond per voxel (which is unacceptable amount of time for me - what is more it uses 4 cores). Call `new_volume=interp(points)` takes about 80% of the prodecure time and the list creation almost whole remaining time.

Is there any simple (or even more complex) way to make this computation faster? Or is there any good Python library, which provides faster interpolation? My volume and points change in every call to this prodecure.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that you are doing the interpolation properly either (hard to say without knowing what `result` is). For array of that size, 37 seconds is not too strange. `points` generation can be speedup a lot, by using `np.c_[ ... ]` instead of `list(zip( ... ))`. Have a look at [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), which will take even longer. If you want quicker interpolation in such array, you will probably have to code your own CUDA code and speedup in the GPU.

Comment: @Imanol Thanks for mentioning the np.c function - I'll try this. The `result [:, :, :, 1]` is the Y grid, `result[:, :, :, 0]` is the X grid, and so on. Regarding the GPU implementation - I'll do this also, but still - more than microsecond for one voxel interpolation using 4 cores is quite high. Even 3-5x speedup would be awesome.

Comment: Have a try for `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` if you want to interpolate on equal binned grid. A wrap can be found [here](https://github.com/syrte/handy/blob/new/interpolate.py)

Comment: My recent experience with RegularGridInterpolator compared to MATLAB's griddedInterpolant is that the former is *MUCH* slower on volumes (I was using vector valued volumes, so a 4D array). So it's quite possible there's a problem with the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is slightly modified version of your `cython` solution:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport floor
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound, nonecheck, cdivision

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
@nonecheck(False)
def interp3D(DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] v, DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] xs, DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] ys, DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] zs):

    cdef int X, Y, Z
    X,Y,Z = v.shape[0], v.shape[1], v.shape[2]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] interpolated = np.zeros((X, Y, Z), dtype=DTYPE)

    _interp3D(&v[0,0,0], &xs[0,0,0], &ys[0,0,0], &zs[0,0,0], &interpolated[0,0,0], X, Y, Z)
    return interpolated


@cdivision(True)
cdef inline void _interp3D(DTYPE_t *v, DTYPE_t *x_points, DTYPE_t *y_points, DTYPE_t *z_points, 
               DTYPE_t *result, int X, int Y, int Z):

    cdef:
        int i, x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1, dim
        DTYPE_t x, y, z, xd, yd, zd, c00, c01, c10, c11, c0, c1, c

    dim = X*Y*Z

    for i in range(dim):
        x = x_points[i]
        y = y_points[i]
        z = z_points[i]

        x0 = <int>floor(x)
        x1 = x0 + 1
        y0 = <int>floor(y)
        y1 = y0 + 1
        z0 = <int>floor(z)
        z1 = z0 + 1

        xd = (x-x0)/(x1-x0)
        yd = (y-y0)/(y1-y0)
        zd = (z-z0)/(z1-z0)

        if x0 >= 0 and y0 >= 0 and z0 >= 0:
            c00 = v[Y*Z*x0+Z*y0+z0]*(1-xd) + v[Y*Z*x1+Z*y0+z0]*xd
            c01 = v[Y*Z*x0+Z*y0+z1]*(1-xd) + v[Y*Z*x1+Z*y0+z1]*xd
            c10 = v[Y*Z*x0+Z*y1+z0]*(1-xd) + v[Y*Z*x1+Z*y1+z0]*xd
            c11 = v[Y*Z*x0+Z*y1+z1]*(1-xd) + v[Y*Z*x1+Z*y1+z1]*xd

            c0 = c00*(1-yd) + c10*yd
            c1 = c01*(1-yd) + c11*yd

            c = c0*(1-zd) + c1*zd

        else:
            c = 0

        result[i] = c
```

The results are still identical to yours. With a random grid data of `60x60x60` I obtain the following timings:

```
SciPy's solution:                982ms
Your cython solution:            24.7ms
Above modified cython solution:  8.17ms
```

So its nearly 4 times faster than your `cython` solution. Note that

1. Cython performs bounds checking by default on arrays and if you want that feature  then turn on boundschecking remove `@boundscheck(False)`.
2. In the above solution the arrays are required to be C-contiguous
3. If you want a parallel variant of the above code, replace `range` instead of `prange` in your `for loop`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed faster, but computes wrong result (the absolute difference between original solution/scipy interpolation and this version is too high) and crashes on bigger grids (200x200x20 for example).

Comment: @Nefarin There was a couple of typos in the code. I had to change a `+` to `*` and now the results are identical to yours. As I mentioned before, make sure the arrays that you pass to this function are `C-contiguous`.

Comment: Thank you, It works now and after releasing the gil and using prange it's even faster.

Comment: I'm looking for something to interpolate some function f(x,y). Is this what you're doing with this code snippet? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're doing here and which interpolation method you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I used Cython to accelerate this and implemented following code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()
from libc.math cimport ceil, floor

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

def interp3(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] x_grid, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] y_grid,
    np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] z_grid, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] v,
    np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] xs, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] ys, 
    np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] zs):

    cdef int i
    cdef float x
    cdef float y
    cdef float z
    cdef int x0
    cdef int x1
    cdef int y0
    cdef int y1
    cdef int z0
    cdef int z1
    cdef float xd
    cdef float yd
    cdef float zd
    cdef float c00
    cdef float c01
    cdef float c10
    cdef float c11
    cdef float c0
    cdef float c1
    cdef float c
    cdef int X
    cdef int Y
    cdef int Z

    X, Y, Z = np.shape(x_grid)

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] x_points = np.ravel(xs)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] y_points = np.ravel(ys)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] z_points = np.ravel(zs)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] result = np.empty((len(x_points)), dtype=DTYPE)

    for i in range(len(x_points)):
        x = x_points[i]
        y = y_points[i]
        z = z_points[i]

        x0 = int(floor(x))
        x1 = x0 + 1
        y0 = int(floor(y))
        y1 = y0 + 1
        z0 = int(floor(z))
        z1 = z0 + 1

        xd = (x-x0)/(x1-x0)
        yd = (y-y0)/(y1-y0)
        zd = (z-z0)/(z1-z0)

        try:
            assert x0 >= 0 and y0 >= 0 and z0 >= 0
            c00 = v[x0, y0, z0]*(1-xd) + v[x1, y0, z0]*xd
            c01 = v[x0, y0, z1]*(1-xd) + v[x1, y0, z1]*xd
            c10 = v[x0, y1, z0]*(1-xd) + v[x1, y1, z0]*xd
            c11 = v[x0, y1, z1]*(1-xd) + v[x1, y1, z1]*xd

            c0 = c00*(1-yd) + c10*yd
            c1 = c01*(1-yd) + c11*yd

            c = c0*(1-zd) + c1*zd
        except:
            c = 0

        result[i] = c

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] interpolated = np.zeros((X, Y, Z), dtype=DTYPE)
    interpolated = np.reshape(result, (X, Y, Z))
    return interpolated
```

It is my first time with Cython, so have following questions:

1. How can I optimize this further?
2. Is there any easy way to avoid try and assert statements to check array bounds? Trying to ensure bounds with min/max combinations is slower than this try/assert approach

Currently, it is around 8x faster than original code posted above.